# How to run Firefox with AT command in Linux?

Tags: linux, scheduled-tasks

I try to run a specified command on a desired time. I found `at` for this, and it seems to work fine if I run:

```
echo "ls -al / > /home/florin/test.txt" | at 4:21am
```

But I want to run a different thing: `/usr/bin/firefox -new-tab http://google.ro`

I tried adapting the first line with my action (running it in terminal opens a new Firefox tab with http://google.ro, so the command is correct), but with `at`, it does not work:

```
echo "firefox -new-tab http://google.ro" | at 4:23am
```

The task seems to be scheduled, but it does not run. When running the previous line I get the default reply from `at`:

```
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
```

Should my Firefox command be differently run in `sh`? Is there a way to do my action with `at`, or some other way?

Comment: The question is: why would you want to do this? Could you achieve the same result using better cli-oriented tools?

Comment: You are right, it is easier with other tools. Installed gnome-schedule, it should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Firefox is a display oriented program requiring access to your X11 display. This information is usually available in an environment variable DISPLAY, but when you run FF from at, this is not the case. Thus FF doesn't know where to put it's graphical output and thus exits immediately.

If you're absolutely sure that you know where your display is going to be (and no pun intended, you can have any number of X11 servers running), you could just put DISPLAY with appropriate content in the beginning of your command you're feeding to at. For example, `DISPLAY=0:0 firefox -new-tab http://google.ro` will open a new tab on FF process runnin on first local X11 display on your computer.